# How to extract scheme and host of a URL once?

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

Imagine this is my URL

```
NSURL *theURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"];
```

How can i extract only:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

?

Comment: what do you want to do? is it for any specific url or dynamic?

Comment: any URL, with HOST Method i can get only "stackoverflow.com" ! i want the complete domain with http, so i can use it again with NSURL Object, because NSURL Object does not accept a URL without scheme!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@", [theURL scheme], [theUrl host]]`

Comment: I tried this by myself, i am wondering if there is a more proper way for this.

Comment: I think this is most compact way of doing what you want.  NSURL has properties that let you access the individual components of a url, but there is no native method that gives back both (and only) the scheme and host at the same time.  If you have to do this a lot in your code you *could* write your own method for this and add it to NSURL with a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`[theURL host]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJDCADG)?

Comment: HOST gives me only "stackoverflow.com" without scheme! i want it with scheme!